# Как слушать websocket на сервере?

Tags: сокет, websocket, socket.io

В общем есть сервер которые дает данные через websocket, так вот, как  получать эти данные на сервере?
В браузере я знаю как получать, нужно что бы данные получал мой сервер.

Comment: серверная часть на каком языке?

Comment: ну обычный сервер типа ubuntu или debian, апач или nginx

Comment: ubuntu, debian, apache or nginx это не языки. Если Java то смотри в сторону класса Endpoint

Comment: Допустим даже сервер может слушать вебсокет, но чтобы сервер знал, что именно делать с пришедшими данными - должен быть какой-либо код. Поэтому вам придётся что-то программировать, а не просто положиться на то, что я "включу модуль слушания вебсокет в сервере и ничего писать не надо" (свести задачу к админской по настройке модуля), да и такой модуль если вообще возможен сможет лишь отправлять пришедшие данные в /dev/null или делать не ту работу что нужно вам. Поэтому ваш вопрос бессмысленнен. Указывайте на чём вы будете писать программу.

Comment: мне не важно на чем, главное случашать сокет с минимальным пингом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример websocket-клиента в приложении на node.js

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const WebsocketReconnectInterval = 2 * 1000;
const WebsocketTerminateInterval = 20 * 1000;
const WebsocketURL = 'wss://example.com';


const ws = new WebSocket(WebsocketURL);
let wsCloseTimer;

ws.on('open', () => {
    console.info('websocket open');
})
.on('error', (...args) => {
    console.warn('websocket error', args);
})
.on('close', (...args) => {
    console.info('websocket close, try to reconnect...', args);
    // setTimeout(()=>this.connect(), WebsocketReconnectInterval);
})
.on('message', (data) => {
    console.info(`ws "no-direct" message ${data}`);
})
.on('ping', () => {
    // закрыть websocket в случае когда с сервера перестанут приходить регулярные ping
    // wsCloseTimer && clearTimeout(wsCloseTimer);
    // wsCloseTimer = setTimeout(() => ws.terminate(), WebsocketTerminateInterval);
})
// .on('pong', (...args) => {})
;
```